# CSS Selector for group of elements?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape an HTML site with this structure:

```
<a name="how"></a>
<div class="ignore"></div>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<h3>...</h3>
<p>...</p>
<ul>...</ul>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<a name="other-uses"></a>
```

I need to grab all of the **p, h3 and ul** tags between the two a[name] anchor elements.

Right now I successfully grabbed the first p:

```
a[name='how'] + div + p
```

but I'm not sure how to grab all of the elements between the two.

This is being used within [ScrAPI ruby scraping library](http://content.labnotes.org/scrapi/scrapi.html) that accepts all valid CSS selectors.

Comment: Does ScrAPI allow for XPath selection?

Comment: Do you need the tags grabbed in the order they exist in the document? Are there additional `<p>`, `<h3>` and `<ul>` tags in the document?

Comment: @Mark Thomas: It doesn't appear to.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in one fell swoop with CSS selectors.

Comment: Is this possible with xpath? I can switch to a different library that supports xpath.

Comment: @dMix, yes, XPath provides a lot more sophistication in selection logic. Perhaps Mechanize (which uses Nokogiri) is an option for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done in a single CSS selector, but would love to be proven wrong.

It can be done in a single XPath expression, however:

```
//*[preceding-sibling::a/@name="how" and following-sibling::a/@name="other-uses"]
```

so if an alternate scraping library is an option, such as Mechanize (which uses Nokogiri, an XPath-compliant HTML parser), then it can be done using the XPath above.

EDIT: for completeness, here's a fully functioning script that demonstrates the xpath using the Nokogiri HTML parser.

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

html =<<ENDOFHTML
<html>
<body>
    <a name="how"></a>
    <div class="ignore"></div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <h3>...</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <ul>...</ul>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <a name="other-uses"></a>
</body>
</html>
ENDOFHTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

puts doc.xpath('//*[preceding-sibling::a/@name="how" and following-sibling::a/@name="other-uses"]')
```

Result:

```
<div class="ignore"></div>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<h3>...</h3>
<p>...</p>
<ul>...</ul>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

Comment: Well, I guess the [syntax highlighting hint](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting) I added didn't improve the look of your Ruby script block. Oh well. And no, I don't think there is any way to do this with CSS selectors.